# How to deal with the values "ratio" when analysing data without using Series in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a column in my table that includes a "female to male ratio" for example: 45 : 55 and I would like to put the values for the females (on the left side, ex. 45) in one column, and the value for the males (on the right side, ex. 55) in a new separate column.

My problem is that I need to do this in Pandas (using a iPython notebook). I have been searching the internet for a solution that does not use Series - it just doesn't seem to work for me. Any suggestions?

Here is a screenshot of what that column and the rows look like:

[Female To Male Ratio Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1uk6.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am certain there is a more elegant way to do this; however here's a quick and dirty option:

```
#Create a function to split the values
def splitter(ratio):
    try: #Try to split the values
        return ratio.split(" : ")[0], ratio.split(" : ")[1]
    except AttributeError: #return None for NaN's
        return None, None
#apply the function to the column
df.loc[:, 'MaleNumerator'], df.loc[:, 'FemaleDenominator'] = zip(*df.male_female_Ratio.apply(splitter))
```

Comment: yes, it worked. I just had to put the second index as [-1] but now it works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help!